# PHP connect to MS Access database - Provider not found

Tags: php, ms-access, wamp, oledb, adodb

I know there are tons of questions about this on SO. But I've been trying to fix this since a month with no luck.

At work we have this very old website that uses an access database, and I cannot do anything about it.I want to work on some changes on my local PC using wamp server. So I donwloaded the website along with the db. Here is how it's supposed to connect :

```
$conn = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$db = realpath("dbalerts.mdb");
$conn->Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=$db");
```

But it's giving me this error:

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: ADODB.Connection 
Description:Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'
in C:\wamp\www\testaccess\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\testaccess\index.php(5): com->Open('Provider=Micros...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\testaccess\index.php on line 5
```

It's a test folder whith an index.php where only that code is written. In the same folder is dbalerts.mdb

I tried everything I know. I downloaded AccessDatabaseEngine.exe from MS website which is supposed to have the driver. And it installed properly with no errors( had to uninstall office because it was 64bit)

I am on a win8 machine

Any ideas how I can fix this all while still using COM and ADODB?  Because I can't go through changing the connections of every .php file in that website (it's old and poorly designed so not adaptable to changes)

Comment: if you are using 64bit driver on a 32bit windows or vise-versa, you get this problem. try to install 32bit office and use an appropriate connection string  https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007/

Comment: What does `echo (8 * PHP_INT_SIZE) . "-bit<br/>";` show you?

Comment: @krishKM t is a 64bit OS. And I had office 64 installed. So I uninstalled office then installed the drivers. Do I need 32 office now ? I dont care about opening it from office , just the drivers and php

Comment: @GordThompson 32-bit

Comment: your application is looking for the driver in the C:\Windows\System32 folder but your drivers are installed in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 Installing 32bit office might solve your problem.